# How to grant root user all privileges while skip-grant-table is enabled

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want to grant all privileges to `root` user in `mysql` database while `skip-grant-tables` is enabled.

How can I do that?

When I disable `skip-grant-tables` options, I cannot login to `mysql` due to this error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

When I run this command, it affect zero rows:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
```

Also:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

does not flush or alter anything.

Database is Mariadb version 10.3.22.

Answer (score 0):

setup 1: when skip-grant-tables is enabled

update user set authentication_string=password("root") where user="root";
flush privileges;

setup 2:
delete skip-grant-tables in my.cnf

setup 3:
restart mysql service

Comment: then grant root privileges;

Comment: I cannot `update` because it does not work when `skip-grant` is enabled.